# Syncing up Woocommerce orders between a live site and staging site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, staging

I've been working on some developmental tweaks and theme updates to a client's website on a staging version. The site has a live ecommerce component, so over the few months that I've worked on it, there have been a whole bunch of orders which are on the live site, but not the staging site.

Since Woocommerce (for some strange reason) keeps orders in the same table as its posts, products, pages etc., many of the order ids have already been "used up" in the staging site, so when I try to import them (using a tool like https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/ ) they desync and the order numbers are wrong. There are a few options here; I could try to divorce the visible order number from the post id #, but this is a bit wonky. I've tried some solutions, but these tend not to work with the import plugins I've used. Alternatively, I could always dig into the mysql tables, but this isn't something I want to do everytime I push from staging to live.

Is anyone willing to share a solution, plugin recco or best practice for dealing with this? Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What are you creating on the staging site? New Products? Test orders? I can't think of anything other than syncing the staging site to the live site more frequently. Perhaps a cron job that will pull in the new orders daily? Or something using the API to update the staging site w/ the new order?

Comment: The major issue is that we're working on several new pages for the site (as well as order testing). Since these live in the same table as orders, they can take up the same ids.

I could use a frequent cron job or an API call triggered by a new order on the live site -- let think about that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot keep the orderID for new import , as WP treating everything as post. You can add it as extra meta with order. It will update if the order is existing in the Database. Also you can rise a [support ticket here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/order-import-export-for-woocommerce) for  help

You can also get a plugin that can manage order extra meta [from here](http://www.xadapter.com/product/order-import-export-plugin-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: Yes! I've been playing with this. It won't quite deal with the issue of inconsistent order numbers, but I'm playing around with using the pro version of Order Export Import for WooCommerce plus a YITH plugin that creates a separate meta ID, different from the one in the table.

Comment: You found the solution or Pro version did it?

Comment: I went pro in order to get the custom meta from YITH working. It's not a bad solution since it totally divorces WooCommerce order #s from specific post IDs. Way safer in my opinion.

Thanks Mujeebu